# Angular IE11 Syntax error vendor.js (124116) class Dom7

Tags: angular, syntax, vendor

When I open my project in IE11 I get

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
>
> vendor.js (124116,1)

When I navigate to vendor.js on the specified line I find

```
class Dom7 {
constructor(arr) {
    const self = this;
    // Create array-like object
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      self[i] = arr[i];
    }
    self.length = arr.length;
    // Return collection with methods
    return this;
  }
}
```

I tried all combinations of the solutions like uncommenting all the pollyfils.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Also targeting es5/es6, changing lib (adding es2016), etc in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
]}
```

Can anyone help, I ran out of ideas

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with dependencies, I have the same issue with ngx-useful-swiper library, you dont need polyfills for this, just tranpile your code to es5 syntax